# input a number in a while loop for a python bowling program

Tags: python

I am making a bowling program. I am at the stage of making a program which records the numbers I input in a list.

```
rolls1 = []
rolls2 = []
rolls3 = []
frame = []
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    n1 = int(input("Roll 1: "))
    rolls1.append(n1)
    if i < 10:
        if n1 == 10:
            rolls2.append(0)
        else:
            n2 = int(input("Roll 2: "))
            rolls2.append(n2)
    elif i == 10:
        if (n1 == 10):
            n2 = int(input("Roll 2: "))
            rolls2.append(n2)
            n3 = int(input("Roll 3: "))
            rolls3.append(n3)
        else:
            if (n1 + n2 == 10):
                n2 = int(input("Roll 2: "))
                rolls2.append(n2)
                n3 = int(input("Roll 3: "))
                rolls3.append(n3)
            else:
                n2 = int(input("Roll 2: "))
                rolls2.append(n2)
```

In the last frame, which is `i == 10`, when I input `n1 = 8`, `n2 = 2`, the program is supposed to move on to input a number in `n3`. However, the program stops at `n2`, and therefore an error occurs in the other part of the program. making an `if` inside `else` doesn't seem to be the solution. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: When i=10, n2 variable is not defined. Therefore, the program cannot properly do the if statement n1 + n2 == 10. The program probably goes to the last else statement.

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't realized my mistake, and I fixed it by taking the n2 out of the if.

Comment: Yes, I just made the answer just before you comment haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `i==10`, `n2` variable is not defined. Therefore, the program cannot properly do the if statement `n1 + n2 == 10`. The program probably goes to the last else statement. Just take the input of `n2` outside the last if-else statement:

```
rolls1 = []
rolls2 = []
rolls3 = []
frame = []
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    n1 = int(input("Roll 1: "))
    rolls1.append(n1)
    if i < 10:
        if n1 == 10:
            rolls2.append(0)
        else:
            n2 = int(input("Roll 2: "))
            rolls2.append(n2)
    elif i == 10:
        n2 = int(input("Roll 2: "))
        if (n1 == 10):
            rolls2.append(n2)
            n3 = int(input("Roll 3: "))
            rolls3.append(n3)
        else:
            if (n1 + n2 == 10):
                rolls2.append(n2)
                n3 = int(input("Roll 3: "))
                rolls3.append(n3)
            else:
                rolls2.append(n2)
```